# How to set SWT label padding?

Tags: java, layout, swt, jface

When i assign text to my `Labels`, they wrap around it very tightly, sometimes cutting the lower edges off 'p', 'y' and alike. I would like to have some padding between text and border. I am using a TableWrapLayout for the parent `Composite` and TableWrapData for the `Labels`

```
    TableWrapLayout layout = new TableWrapLayout();
    layout.numColumns = 2;
    layout.bottomMargin = 10;
    layout.topMargin = 10;
    client.setLayout(layout);

    Label label= toolkit.createLabel(client, "", SWT.NONE);
```

We are using the FormToolkit for consistent design, IMHO this has no influence on border painting

Comment: Sending part of your code might be more helpful.

Doesn't TableWrapLayout.[bottom/top]Margin or verticalSpacing work?

Comment: @Mohsen : added some source code for clarity. xxxMargin and xxSpacing both work but do sth different - margin generates a margin around all Controls of the Composite, and spacing generates spacing between individual Controls. What i need is a margin/padding INSIDE the Label - some space around the text

Comment: In some simple cases, adding an invisible horizontal separator between the labels could be enough: `GridDataFactory.swtDefaults().align(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER).grab(true, false).applyTo(new Label(shell, SWT.HORIZONTAL | SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.SHADOW_NONE));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layout (such as GridLayout) and LayoutData (e.g. GridData) objects in SWT can only control spacing outside a control (so they may only set margins, not padding). In order to change control side itself you can only use `setSize()` and `setBound()`.

Comment: so it means sth like 'Point p = label.getSize(); p.x +=4; p.y += 4; label.setSize(p);' Seems kludgy but actually works, as a good kludge should :)

Comment: Yes, something like what you write.

Answer (score 4):

(Answer many years later, but still an answer...)

```
CLabel cl = new CLabel(shell, SWT.CENTER);
int padding = 5;
cl.setMargins(padding, padding, padding, padding);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Quoting my answer to a similar question:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29004864/720425)

> I also wrestled with this issue. `Label` does not support padding. I wound up using `StyledText` instead.
>
> ```
>    final StyledText text = new StyledText(parent, SWT.WRAP);
>    final int padding = 5;
>
>    text.setLeftMargin(padding);
>    text.setRightMargin(padding);
>    text.setTopMargin(padding);
>    text.setBottomMargin(padding);
>
>    text.setWordWrap(true);
>    text.setCaret(null);
> ```
>
> This did the trick for me.